# Calculate Pause time for the Milestone across each Team when status = Pending?

Tags: trigger, entitlements

I am using `Entitlement Processes and Milestones`. I have 5 teams (`Team-A to Team-E`). Any Team can get the Case assigned to their queue.

- When case is assigned to `Team-A` and `Status=Pending`, then need to calculate/capture the time case was in **Pending** with that team.
- When case is assigned to `Team-B` and `Status=Pending`, then need to calculate/capture the time case was in **Pending** with that team.

and So on

I have developed workflows (so far just 2 workflow), when Status=Pending, making Entitlement Process Pause. Doing field update `IsStopped=true` and `On Hold Start Time=Now()`

When `Status != Pending`, making Entitlement Process running. Doing field update `IsStopped=false` and `On Hold Time=PRIORVALUE(On_Hold_Time__c)+NOW()- DATETIMEVALUE(On_Hold_Start_Time__c)`

- How can I calculate the overall Time the Case was in Pending status with each time and time that team took to sent back to other team.
- How can I calculate the overall Time the Case was in Pending status across multiple team.
- Do I need to follow the same process for other 4 teams, create a separate workflow team wise and do the field updates? Or Do I need to write a trigger logic for the same ?

Any approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way you can create 2 fields as:

1. Team Name (text)
2. On hold Time (which you have created)

and mark both of them as **history tracking**

This way, you can track each team's on hold time.

Secondly, if you want consolidate total on-hold time, then create a number field which calculates the total duration in seconds and update this value from trigger when when you are updating on-hold time.

As per my understanding, you want to calculate timing based on status rather than team, so team specific workflow is not needed.